# Hall's theorem proof - capacity of middle edges

Tags: graph-theory

The Hall's theorem say that for un-directed bipartite graph $G=(U,W,E)$ and

$$|U|=|W|=n,$$

there is a prefect matching if and only if for every subset $X$ of $U$, 
$$|X|\le |N(X)|.$$

I read the proof of Hall's theorem and I didn't understand the direction we assume that for every subset $X$ of $U$, $|X|\le |N(X)|$ and we want to prove that there is a perfect matching.

In the proof we convert the graph to flow network and we put inifinity to the middle edges' capacity (the edges between $U$ and $W$)

> Why we can't put $1$ to those capacities, why we have to put infinity?
>   thanks.

The proof:

Proof. We first notice that the condition above is trivially necessary for a perfect matching to exist; indeed, if we had a subset $S \subset V_1$ with $|S| > |N(S)|$, then there is no way to match up all of the $|S|$ elements of $S$ along edges with elements in $V_2$ without using some elements more than once.

We now prove that our condition is sufficient, via the Max-Flow Min-Cut theorem. Take our graph $G$, orient all of its edges so that they go from $V_1$ to $V_2$, add a source vertex $s$, a sink vertex $t$, edges from $s$ to all of $V_1$, from all of $V_2$ to $t$, and let $c$ be a capacity function that’s identically $1$ on all of the edges $s \to V_1$, $t \to  V_2$, **and $\infty$ on all of the original edges in $G$.** By Ford-Fulkerson, there is a minimal cut on this graph: call it $S$. We trivially know that $c(S, S) \le n$, as there is a $n$-cut given by simply setting $S = \{s\}$; we seek to show that $c(S, S)$ is in fact equal to $n$.

Let $X = S \cap V_1$. Because the capacity of all of the edges originally in $G$  is infinite, we know that any minimal cut cannot contain half of any such edges; therefore, we have
$$N(X) \subset S\cap V_2.$$

http://math.ucsb.edu/~padraic/mathcamp_2011/flows_graphs/MC2011_flows_graphs_wk2_day2.pdf

Comment: I'm sorry if you already knew this but just so you know there are quite a few simple proofs of Hall that don't use flows.

Comment: I want to know this because I'm learning flows.

Comment: This is going to be pretty hard to answer if you don't tell us the proof.

Comment: @Callus : The proof has just been given.